# How to access smarty's foreach iteration from php function? (Smarty 2.6)

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

## Question

Say I have

```
{php}
    function hello(){
{/php}
    <div class="hello">{$smarty.foreach.panellist.iteration}</div>
{php}
    }
{/php}
```

Then down below I call:

```
{foreach from=$channelObj->get_panellist_primary('','','pan_ptyid,pan_label1,pan_label2') item=panelObj name=panellist}
        {php}hello(){/php}
{/foreach}
```

I'm getting this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /var/www.app1/theURL/otherthings/channel.tpl.php on line 197`

Why doesn't this work? How can I access the iteration of this foreach from inside the function, preferably without passing a parameter?

## More Details

Since I know you'll tell me `{php}` is deprecated...the reason I am using it is because I'm being asked to make a really complicated template, so I need complicated functions to build it without it becoming a mess, and I've never used smarty before. I'm on a deadline and I'm already late, so I can't learn the correct methodology of smarty. The only way I would know how to manage this code is with regular PHP, but my boss is insisting I make the whole thing with smarty...no PHP or Javascript allowed.

Thanks!

Comment: If "no PHP ... allowed", then uh... `{php}` isn't allowed, right? :)  Seriously, can you [are you allowed a plugin](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/smarty-templates-create-custom-functions/)?  If not, your life may be harder to the point of being SOL...

Comment: This looks like a classic [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: you've stumbled into something you don't know how to do in Smarty (to do with writing reusable blocks of code), started down a route you thought would be easy, and ended up with a different thing you don't know how to do in Smarty (to do with mixing PHP and Smarty in non-standard ways). You'll probably find that going back to the original problem is a better use of your time than struggling on with the wrong approach.

Comment: @bishop...naw I can use whatever I just have to work in the .tpl file...I don't have access to the class

Comment: @IMSoP I've gone down many paths I just need help on how to do this. I can do it with a bunch of spaghetti smarty code but I want to avoid that. I want the smarty code to look like, for example, `{wrapperIfNecessary()}{content}{closeWrapperIfNecessary()}`

Comment: The alternative would be `{if \\thing || \\thing and \\thing eq thing}<div>divdivdivdivdivdivdivdiv....etc{/if>{content}{if really long if statement that makes it not even worth using smarty etc}</div></div></div></div></div><div>hello</div></div></div>{/if}`

Comment: And keep in mind that I don't get to assign the variables to smarty myself so I have nothing to work with...I asked a specific question and I just need it answered.

Comment: @bishop I don't think I can really create a plugin because I only have access to the one .tpl file

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Trying to source that error: if you remove the call to `hello()` does the problem go away?  If you remove the `{$smarty.foreach.panellist.iteration}` does the problem disappear?

Comment: @bishop yes...removing `{$smarty.foreach.panellist.iteration}` makes it disappear. Everything works if I just output normal HTML in the hello function.

Comment: Rather than using the Smarty object built-ins, can you pass `$panelObj` to `hello`, as in: `hello($panelObj)` and get what you need with that?  What do you need in `hello`, incidentally?

Comment: Basically I have a number of `article` tags in a row, styled differently depending on a value. Sometimes the style requires div wrappers around the article tags. Rather than having all this spaghetti logic in my template, I want to simply put the wrapper and have it not show up if its not required. So for example, {startCarousel}{content}{endCarousel}. If the current item in the foreach loop meets certain conditions, then the carousel start and end smarty tags will show. If not, they wont. My only alternative is to clutter my template with long if statements that access a class.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a Smarty 2.6 alternative for `{function}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**scope=global** 
 is required for access variable from foreach!

```
{assign var=SenderID value=$Nachricht.sender_id scope=global} 
{php} echo $smarty->getTemplateVars('SenderID'); {/php}
```

or

> {assign var="edit_ticket_id"
>   value=$ticket.ticketRaw['edit_old_ticket_id'] scope=global}
>
> {php}
>   global $smarty;
>   var_dump($smarty->get_template_vars('edit_ticket_id'));
>   {/php}

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible style of coding, it's not a solution to use such code because you are in hurry. And if you don't know at all some technology, you shouldn't take money for this.

You could use in Smarty:

```
{foreach from=$x item=panelObj name=panellist}
    {assign var="iteration" value=$smarty.foreach.panellist.iteration}
    {php}hello(){/php}
{/foreach}
```

And in PHP function:

```
function hello()
{
    global $smarty;
    ?>
    <div class="hello"><?php echo $smarty->get_template_vars('iteration'); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

and it will work (I've tested it) but I wouldn't even try to use such code for any project

Comment: Theres no way to access iteration directly from $smarty without assigning it?

Comment: @NickManning I don't know the other way